# Sorting a two column table into a multi-column table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Attribute  Value
A          1
B          2
A          5
B          7
C          2
D          9
A          4
B          2
C          4
```

I want to transform that into a sheet that looks like

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  2  9
5  7  4
4  2
```

So I can feed it into a Box-and-whisker chart generator in Mac excel.

Any thoughts on the easiest way to do this? I may have to do it over and over. The dataset may consist of >100,000 rows, but a reasonable amount of attributes (e.g. less than 200).

Comment: Please provide what you tried so we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Excel 365.

In **D1** enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A10))
```

In **D2** enter:

```
=FILTER($B2:$B10,$A2:$A10=D$1)
```

Then copy **D2** to **E2** through**G2** *(or beyond)*:

[image]